# LocationListener keeps on working even after removing updates from its LocationManager and setting it to null

Tags: java, android, locationmanager, locationlistener

I'm trying to make a LocationListener to stop after a fragment is detached, I've checked that the following code is executed:

```
 @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerBest);
        locationListenerBest=null;
    }
```

Location manager starts requesting updates with this:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, LOCATION_UPDATE_MIN_TIME, LOCATION_UPDATE_MIN_DISTANCE, locationListenerBest);
```

So I don't see a reason why it wouldn't just stop requesting updates once that onDetach method is executed.

Why could that happen?

Edit, due to @AlexTa request I'm showing the code used to instatiate locationManager.

```
locationManager =(LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Log and check whether the onDetach method is even being called

Comment: @FilipSollár, yes it does, as I'm saying I've checked that, I entered debug mode and I saw method being executed.

Comment: Are you getting long term continues updates, or just a few more?  If its just a few, this sounds like a race condition with updates that were already scheduled.

Comment: @GabeSechan, they are long term, even a minute after finishing it keeps on executing.

Comment: Could you post the code that shows how do you instantiate and set the LocationManager?

Comment: Sure, already edited my question.

Comment: Still missing how do you instantiate and set the listener... Give some context not just a single line...